# Is there a way to see exception message in unit test during unit test?

Tags: django, unit-testing, python-unittest

When I get 500 status code instead of 200 in my test

```
   responce = requests.post(url)
   self.assertEqual(responce.status_code, 200)
```

I see this message in my console

```
self.assertEqual(responce.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 500 != 200
```

Everyting is fine, but I want to see more information about what actualy happens.
I mean django exception like ViewDoesNotExist or other types of the django exceptions that appear in debug page.
Can I somehow put this information in my terminal during test process?

Comment: If you want to test your views and templates you should use `Client`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it this way

```
    try:
        outdata = json.loads(responce.content)
    except Exception, err:  
        for par in re.findall('<pre class="exception_value">(.*?)<\/pre>',responce.content):
            print '#######%s######' % par
```